# How to get my JLabel Icons to render in my JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

So I have a `JList` of `JLabel` objects that have an Image and some Text attached to them.

[image: Results]

Everything looking good except for the fact that the icons are not displaying the images.

```
public static void createIcons(){
    char[] extension = new char[4];
    Image img;
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < FtpClient.FilesOnServer.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                extension[3 - j] = FtpClient.FilesOnServer[i].charAt(FtpClient.FilesOnServer[i].length() - (j+1));
                if(j == 3) {
                    System.out.println(extension);
                    String fileType = new String(extension);
                    JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel();
                    switch (fileType){
                    case ".pdf":
                        iconLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FtpWindow.class.getResource("icons\\text.png")));
                        break;
                    case ".png":
                        iconLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FtpWindow.class.getResource("icons\\picture.png")));
                        break;
                    case ".jpg":
                        iconLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FtpWindow.class.getResource("icons\\picture.png")));
                        break;
                    case ".txt":
                        iconLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FtpWindow.class.getResource("icons\\text.png")));
                        break;
                    default:
                        iconLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FtpWindow.class.getResource("icons\\default.png")));
                        break;
                    }
                    iconLabel.setText(FtpClient.FilesOnServer[i]);
                    iconLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                    iconLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                    model.addElement(iconLabel);
                }
            }
        }
        T_FileLayout = new JList(model);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void BuildFtpWindow(){
    P_FilesOnServer = new JPanel();
    B_UPLOAD.setBounds(10, 9, 110, 25);
    B_UPLOAD.setText("UPLOAD");
    B_DOWNLOAD.setBounds(10, 39, 110, 25);
    B_DOWNLOAD.setText("DOWNLOAD");
    P_FilesOnServer.setBounds(130, 9, 320, 288);
    P_FilesOnServer.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    createIcons();
    P_FilesOnServer.add(T_FileLayout);
    ServerBrowser.add(P_FilesOnServer);
    ServerBrowser.add(B_DOWNLOAD);
    ServerBrowser.add(B_UPLOAD);
}
```

I have seen a post about overriding `DefaultListCellRenderer`, but I have no idea what I am supposed give it for Object Value. I am just trying to display the Icon and the Text that go with it. I feel like I am close, but just cannot figure out why its not behaving.

Getting similar behavior like before, it appears to be giving a reference to the object instead of rendering them.[New Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3YQZ.png)

Here is the class I created (it is in its own class file and not butted up against the code after it). And the calls along with the overridden function.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ServerFileIcon{

  public ImageIcon Image;
  public String Text;

  public void setImage(String path){
      Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
  }

  public void setText(String text){
      Text = text;
  }

  public ImageIcon getIcon(){
      return Image;
  }

  public String getText(){
      return Text;
  }
}

ServerFileIcon iconLabel = new ServerFileIcon();
              switch (fileType){
                  case ".pdf":
                    iconLabel.setImage("icons\\text.png");
                    break;
                  case ".png":
                    iconLabel.setImage("icons\\picture.png");
                    break;
                  case ".jpg":
                    iconLabel.setImage("icons\\picture.png");
                    break;
                  case ".txt":
                    iconLabel.setImage("icons\\text.png");
                    break;
                  default:
                    iconLabel.setImage("icons\\default.png");
                    break;
              }
              iconLabel.setText(FtpClient.FilesOnServer[i]);
              model.addElement(iconLabel);
            }
          }
      }
      T_FileLayout = new JList(model);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 

   @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) 
    {
       super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        ServerFileIcon customObject = (ServerFileIcon)value;

        setText( customObject.getText() );
        setIcon( customObject.getIcon() );

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit wasn't aware that you could do that

Comment: You can embed the image in your question if you have enough reputation (minimum 10 IIRC). Other people can edit it in though, that's what I did.

Comment: @TT is this question still visible? still looking for some help

Comment: `..getResource("icons\\default.png")` should probably be more along the lines of `..getResource("/icons/default.png")` //

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I have a JList of JLabel objects

You should not be using JLabel objects in your JList. Swing components use renderers to be more efficient.

Instead you should create a custom Object that has 2 properties: text, icon. Then in the rendering code you just set the text and the icon of the renderer (which by default is a JLabel) with the values from your custom object.

> I have seen a post about overriding DefaultListCellRenderer, but I have no idea what I am supposed give it for Object Value.

The Object value will be the custom object mentioned above.

So the basic code would be something like:

```
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
{
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

    MyCustomObject customObject = (MyCustomObject)value;

    setText( customObject.getText() );
    setIcon( customObject.getIcon() );

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Ok so make class that has two things an Image and some text, and then has two assessor methods. Create those Objects like I was doing with the labels. Save those objects into the Vector. Pass the vector to the List. and then override that function. Once I override that function(I have already extended my class to DefaultListCellRenderer) I don't have to call the getListCellRendererComponent method correct?

Comment: @chewbapoclypse, `I don't have to call the getListCellRendererComponent method correct?` - Correct, the JList calls this method for you whenever it need to render an Object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! The JList also has its own Action Listener? So I can get the Text from the object on click.

Comment: @chewbapoclypse, no a JList doesn't have an ActionListener. When you click a a JList an item is selected. Then you can get the selected Item, cast is to your custom object and get the text. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and working examples. Maybe the ListSelectionListener is what you are looking for.

Comment: @chewbapoclypse, `Getting similar behavior like before,` the rendering code is NOT part of your custom object that you add to the JList. You create a custom renderer by extending the DefaultLIstCellRenderer. You stated in your question that you have seen a post about overriding the DefaultListCellRenderer. I just provided the custom code. If you don't know how to do this, then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) which contains a section on this. You also need to set the renderer for the list.

Comment: It is not in the class that the custom object..... it is in the class that uses the JList, I am not sure where thought that happen? `(it is in its own class file and not butted up against the code after it).` (Referring to the code that I had in my post above) I guess I should have separated those two bits. This sounds like what I need `You also need to set the renderer for the list.`

Comment: Thanks camickr! what I was doing wrong, was not applying the renderer to the list I already up voted your answer. This is solved as far as I am concerned. Do I need to update the Question to show my changed code?

Comment: Well, actually in the future when you post code you should post code in the form of a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). That is only the minimal amount of code required to demonstrate the problem and the code should be compilable so we can test it if we wish. It helps us understand the question and  you (might) get a more specific answer instead of a generic answer as was done here. Since you code is not in that format I don't see a need to post the changed code since we don't know the context of how all your code works together anyway.